# Advantages of stack-based bytecodes or infinite register machines

Tags: compiler-construction, expression-trees, intermediate-code

Compilers often choose intermediate representations (IRs) that are either stack-based or infinite register. What are the advantages of these over expression trees?

Comment: One advantage I can think of is that expression trees are a bit harder to represent as a series of bytes, whereas a stack-based VM program is very naturally translatable to a byte stream.

Comment: @romkyns:  for a compiler IL, that hardly matters; all you need is a set of data structures linked by indexes/pointers.

Answer (score 19):

Expression trees work for expressions, but aren't effective for modeling the entire program.  In particular, a good representation of a program is really a graph (of operations and actions) connected by control and data flows.  Usually people talk about using "triples" which form exactly such a graph.

Stack machine code is easy for the front end to generate, but harder for the eventual register allocation process needed to generate real code, because it has a set of temp locations ("the stack") that have nothing clearly to do with the target architecture, and make the dataflows inconvenient to process. ("which code uses the result of this add?").

Register machines are a bit harder to generate code for, but tend to preserve the dataflow by using those infinite registers as essentially data flow wires.  That dataflow and the ability to allocate it easily to real registers (there's a standard register allocation "by graph coloring") makes it relatively easy to generate good code.

If you decide to generate virtual machine code directly from these, you get different performance characteristics.  Essentially, stack machines tend to get smaller code footprints. Infinite register machines tend to get fast interpretive execution. Google's Dalvik is different from the JVM for precisely this reason.  (Maybe they didn't want to get sued by Sun/Oracle over class file formats, too.)

I suggest the following document: [Virtual Machine Showdown: Stack Versus Registers](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/vee05/full_papers/p153-yunhe.pdf). (PS: anything with Anton Ertl as an author tends to be an interesting read).

Comment: I was posting the exact same answer! :D BTW, I would also say that stack VM are easier to start because it's easier to generate code for them...

Comment: I find it disappointing that your answer compares Stack vs Register, while the question asks about Expression Trees vs Stack/Register.

Comment: @romkyns: Fair enough.  Answer revised.

Comment: Link is broken, yo! Try https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/vee05/full_papers/p153-yunhe.pdf

Comment: You answer seems disjoint to me. You said that expression trees "aren't effective for modeling the entire program" but haven't explained why, then said that "a good representation of a program is really a graph" only to go on and discuss exclusively stack and infinite register when neither are graphs. Surely a tree is closer to a graph than a flat list of bytecode ops?!

Comment: A list of register-machine instructions *is* essentially a graph; the opcode are nodes, and assigned-to/read-from registers act as arcs between nodes.  This is complicated by control flow merges; a good model of the graph inserts so-called "phi" nodes to model where multiple register assignments are merged in corresponding ways to the merges of the control flow graph. In essenece this conversts the program into "single assignment". I think you are a functional programmer; you might enjoy the idea that phi nodes convert side-effecting programs into essentially side-effect free programs...

Comment: ... and while an explicit tree by itself is "closer" to a graph, push stack machines don't make the tree explicit (you have to extract it) and most (procedural) programs aren't just expressions (so the other side effects have to extracted from the push stack stack machine, too. All this aside, if you want to build a faster interpreter, the register machine wins because in essence all the necessary resources ("registers") have been preallocated; there's not guessing where you have to "save" that intermediate result.

Comment: ... uh, why did it take you two years to decide this?

Comment: @IraBaxter: "uh, why did it take you two years to decide this?". I am a slow thinker. Let me mull over what you've said. I'll get back to you in 2017. ;-)